# How unshuffle function in Python?

Tags: python, shuffle

I need to unshuffle function in Python. My code is:

```
def deshuffle_order(sftxt,order):
    sftxt_out=[None]*len(sftxt)
    for i, j in enumerate(order):
        sftxt_out[j]=sftxt[i]
    return sftxt_out

print(deshuffle_order('cbda',[2,1,3,0]))
```

I want the results of `abcd` but when I run my code the output is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: `return ''.join(sftxt_out)`

Answer (score 2):

For doing this you will have to do a small change in your code

```
def deshuffle_order(sftxt,order):
    sftxt_out=[None]*len(sftxt)
    for i, j in enumerate(order):
        sftxt_out[j]=sftxt[i]
    return ''.join(sftxt_out)

print(deshuffle_order('cbda',[2,1,3,0]))
```

as `join` will return a string